# Quantum Measurement and Purification

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-measurements

> $\{p_i,|\psi_i\rangle\}$ is an ensemble of states generating a density matrix $\rho= \sum_i {p_i}|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|$ for a quantum system $A$. Introduce a system $R$ with orthonormal basis $|i\rangle$ then  $\sum_i\sqrt{p_i}|\psi\rangle| i\rangle$ is a purification of $ρ$.

> 1. Suppose we measure $R$ in the basis $|i\rangle$, obtaining outcome $i$. With what probability do we obtain the result $i$, and what is the corresponding state of system $A$ ?

> 2. Let $|AR\rangle$ be any purification of $ρ$ to the system $AR$. Show that there exists an orthonormal basis $|i\rangle$ in which $R$ can be measured such that the corresponding post-measurement state for system $A$ is $|\psi_i\rangle$ with probability $p_i$.

**My Attempt**

$$
\rho^A=\sum_i{p_i}|\psi_i\rangle\otimes\langle\psi_i|\\
|AR\rangle=\sum_i \sqrt{p_i}|\psi_i\rangle\otimes|i\rangle\implies |AR\rangle\langle AR|=\sum_{j,k} \sqrt{p_ip_j}|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_j|\otimes|i\rangle\langle j|\\
tr_{R}(|AR\rangle\langle AR|)=\sum_i p_i|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|=\rho^A
$$
**1(a)**

We have the measurement $P|m\rangle=m|m\rangle$
$$
p({m})=tr\Big((I\otimes P)|AR\rangle\langle AR|\Big)=tr\Big((I\otimes P)\sum_{i,j} \sqrt{p_ip_j}|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_j|\otimes|i\rangle\langle j| \Big)=tr\Big(\sum_{i,j} \sqrt{p_ip_j}|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_j|\otimes P|i\rangle\langle j| \Big)=\sum_{i,j} \sqrt{p_ip_j}tr(|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_j|)\otimes tr(P|i\rangle\langle j|)\\=\sum_{i,j} \sqrt{p_ip_j}\langle\psi_i|\psi_j\rangle\otimes tr(P|i\rangle\langle j|)=\sum_{i,j} \sqrt{p_ip_j}\delta_{i,j}\otimes tr(P|i\rangle\langle j|)=\sum_{i} {p_i}. tr(P|i\rangle\langle i|)=\sum_{i} {p_i}. \langle i|P|i\rangle={p_m} \langle m|P|m\rangle={p_m}. m\langle m|m\rangle=mp_m
$$
$$
|AR\rangle_P=(I\otimes P)|AR\rangle=(I\otimes P)\sum_i \sqrt{p_i}|\psi_i\rangle\otimes | i\rangle=\sum_i \sqrt{p_i}|\psi_i\rangle\otimes P| i\rangle=\sqrt{p_m}|\psi_m\rangle\otimes | m\rangle\\
|AR\rangle_P\langle AR|_P=(\sqrt{p_m}|\psi_m\rangle\otimes | m\rangle)(\sqrt{p_m}\langle\psi_m|\otimes \langle m|)=p_m|\psi_m\rangle\langle\psi_m|\otimes|m\rangle\langle m|
$$
**1(b)**

The state of system $A$ after the measurement is,
$$\rho^A_P=tr_R(|AR\rangle_P\langle AR|_P)=tr_R(p_m|\psi_m\rangle\langle\psi_m|\otimes|m\rangle\langle m|)=p_m|\psi_m\rangle\langle\psi_m|\otimes tr(|m\rangle\langle m|)=p_m|\psi_m\rangle\langle\psi_m|$$

Am I doing it right ? how do I approach the rest of the problem ?